# Salesforce functions - No access to Calculation Matrix related Objects

Tags: salesforce-functions

We are using Salesforce functions which uses Calculation Matrix tables. we are getting following error when trying to run the code from compute environment.

{"error":true,"errorMessage":"\nSelect id from CalculationMatrix where Name = 'Distribution\n               ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:16\nsObject type 'CalculationMatrix' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."}

We tried providing access through a permission set but we cannot give access to this calculation Matrix objects because the permission set is assigned to "Platform Integration User". if we remove the permission set to this user and run Functions from Compute environment it fails to get access to custom objects. Has anyone encountered this issue? How to handle and access BRE tables from Functions Compute environment?

Comment: It seems that this object requires an Omnistudio license. Have you granted that?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_calculationmatrix.htm

Comment: Yes we tried that option as well. Still getting the same error.

Comment: More specifically, that user needs the 'Rule Engine Runtime' permission set, rather than a general Omnistudio one. Just confirming that you have tried added that to the integration user? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.decision_matrices.htm&type=5